# Xamarin.Auth uses WebView which is going to get deprecated by Google soon

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-oauth, xamarin.auth

I'm using Xamarin.Auth with Google API, which I believe uses "embedded" browser to issue OAuth requests and provide UI.

But Google announced that such a way of authentication is deprecated:

> Starting October 20, 2016, we will prevent new OAuth clients from
>   using web-views on platforms with a viable alternative, and will phase
>   in user-facing notices for existing OAuth clients. On April 20, 2017,
>   we will start blocking OAuth requests using web-views for all OAuth
>   clients on platforms where viable alternatives exist.

Is this going to affect me?

Comment: Yes it will. Watch [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/150#issuecomment-284055926) for an eventual fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this going to affect me?

Not if your app created (credentials) on the server side is older (I think older than 2016-08 or a bit eariler)

Here you have samples with nativeUI (Custom Tabs and SafariViewController)

https://github.com/moljac/Xamarin.Auth.Samples.NugetReferences

In providers sample solution I have project created in 2015 which still works with WebViews